# How to retrieve a text values by filtering dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with contents (number 6) and respective review dates in three columns (numbers 1, 2 and 3).

I would like to select a day (number 4) and Excel to retrieve all content to be reviewed that day (number 5), in the orange cells.[image]

Comment: Your description seems "over-complicated", might be you have to describe in more detail to allow use understand what you're trying to achieve. As it looks now you migh tbe better off selecting the "current" date in one of the review columns (Autofilter assumed!) at a time.

Comment: you can use power query to unpivot the table, then you can just filter on a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column called Include to your table of data. Use this formula:

```
=OR(H3:J3=$C$3)
```

This will show TRUE if any of the dates in that row matches your filter date.

Then use this formula to filter the content labels:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(G3:G11,K3:K11))
```

This just says filter column G for any row that has a TRUE in column K. It's wrapped in UNIQUE to make sure we don't see the same label twice in the case of more than one review of the same content on the same day.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly and solved a long term problem I had! 